# All fixtures in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, fixtures, rspec-rails

I guess I am missing something very very obvious, but in my RSpec tests I want to do something like this:

```
it "should assign all channels to @channels" do                                                                                                                                                                      
  get :index                                                                                                                                                                                         
  assigns(:channels).should eq(channels(:all))                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

As you can see I want all channels in an array for my tests so I don't have to fix all my tests when I add a new fixture in the future.

`channels(:all)` is not working and `channels.kind_of? Array` is true and empty by default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might need is:

```
assigns(:channels).should eq(Channel.all)
```

Comment: Bloody obvious.. why didn't i think about that.. Thanks!